# Configure Azure Active Directory to prompt for account type

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, windows-live-id, microsoft-account

I authenticate my application with an Azure Active Directory, and I have an email address that is both a Microsoft account (former Live ID) and an Office 365 account. I add the email as an existing Microsoft account to my AAD. However, when I go to the application sign in page and enter this email, I am automatically redirected to the organizational sign in page (Office 365 sign in page) and unable to log in with the Microsoft account.

I assume that it is possible to prompt the user for their account type prior to sign in (similar to how Azure Portal itself does it). How can the AAD be configured to prompt for the account type?

Answer (score 1):

So, according to Microsoft this is not currently possible and they are working on the fix.

A workaround: if you enter an email that *does not* belong to an organizational directory (you can enter a@gmail.com, for instance) at the application sign in page, you will be redirected to a Microsoft account sign in page. After that you can enter your work email and sign in with your Microsoft credentials successfully.